# Image Not Displaying with CSS Enabled

Tags: css

I'm just trying to dead center this image in the middle of the page. Here is my very simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Viva La Nation</title>
    <style>
        #centered {
            margin-left: -148px;
            position: absolute;
            top: -285px;
            left: 50%;
            width: 570px;
            height: 296px;
        }

        body {
            background-image:url('seamless.png');
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh"    
content="10;url=http://www.vivalanation.com/forums">

<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/forums/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 10000)">
  <div id="centered">
    <a href="http://www.vivalanation.com/forums/forum.php">
     <img src="images/logo_nin.png" style="border:0px"  />
    </a>        
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

If I cut out the CSS code, the image shows up. I followed this icnonic page to dead center the image: http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html, but for some reason it won't show. And I know it certainly is the CSS, I just don't know where I'm going wrong at. The total specs of the image are 570x296.

Oh, I just found it, it's WAY up at the top of the screen, the bottom of the text is barely visible.

Answer (score 0):

set margin to  "auto"  and according to the size of the image set top in percentages.

Comment: Like this?

#centered {
margin-left: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 570px;
height: 296px;
}

Answer (score 0):

You have set `top` to the value that you want to use for `margin-left`, and `margin-left` to the value that you want to use for `margin-top`. The `top` values should be `50%`:

```
#centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 570px;
    height: 296px;
    margin-left: -285px;
    margin-top: -148px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/GMfSB/

Comment: Ahh OK, I gave those settings a go, it's way off center (see attached image).

http://i.imgur.com/Rhs6FnC.png

Nevermind, it's fixed. Thank you so much, Guffa!

Comment: @Whitechapel: It looks like you missed with the left margin. Check the spelling and syntax in the CSS.

Comment: Yes sir, I took care of it and it looks great! Thank you!